# Not able to access library module dependecies while using implementation instead of compile

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-glide

while using `compile` keyword to add dependencies in `gradle`,i am able to access all the dependencies of library module.

But while using `implementation` keyword, i am not able to access those dependencies in app module ,available in  library module `gradle` file.

**My Framework dependency**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' 
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1' 
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1' 
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0' 
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0' 
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0' 
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0' 
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2' 
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1' 
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1' 
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0' 
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
}
```

**My App dependence**

```
dependencies {
implementation project(':framework')
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

**Issue**

> If i use `compile` keyword for compiling dependencies, it works. If i
>   use `implementation` keyword for compiling dependences, it doesn't
>   work

**Issue screen-shot**

[image]

Comment: try with api fileTree(...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **api** instead of **implemenation**.
**api** keyword will allow you to use dependencies in all the modules